# src of the custom-logo img-tag is missing and not rendered in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the template "Twentyseventeen" and created a child theme of it.
Now I added the_custom_logo(); to header.php and the custom-logo link is rendered,
but without the img src. So I have a blank space. I searched now for hours and can't find the reason. Even if I switch back to orignal Twentyseventeen theme the img src was missing. Well I'm not very famiiar to wordpress and if anybody could help me to fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) try to add `<img>` like this

```
<img src="<?php the_custom_logo();?>"/>
```

In my theme I use This:

```
<div class="logo">
        <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">
            <?php $logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );?>
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $logo_id , 'full' ); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
```

I hope that it help you :)

Comment: I tried it, but same thing as before it is rendered,b ut without src.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you don't have custom logo set in the backend or it needs a reset.

- Go to the Admin Dashboard > Appearance > Customizer > Site Identity
- Check if you've set the custom logo there. If it is set, remove it
  and reset it.

If you don't see any option to set custom logo there, your theme doesn't support custom logo option. In this case `the_custom_logo()` or related functions will not work. Read [this guide](https://digitalsetups.com/wp-support-custom-logo/) to add support for custom logo and then using the URL or printing the logo with markup.